# Jutifying: irrational + rational = irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I am not sure how to show this. This is what I tried.

Proposition:
**If x is rational number and y is an irrational number then x+y is an irrational number.**

Logically speaking this is

P=x is rational

Q= Y is irrational

R= x+y is irrational

$P\wedge Q \rightarrow R$

**Explanation:**
What I did

$x=\frac{p}{q}$ P and Q integer

Y cannot be written as the a rational by definition

So therefore

$x+y=\frac{p}{q}+y$

Will not be a rational number as there cannot be a common denominator.

Comment: This doesn't do the trick as you claim what is to be shown. Assume that $x+y$ is rational show and that this implies that $y$ is rational.

Comment: you mean I have to do the contra postive (If x+y is rational then either x is irrational or y is rational) ?

Comment: No, note that $\sqrt 2 - \sqrt 2 = 0$ is rational, but neither is $\sqrt 2$, nor $-\sqrt 2$.Instead show: "If $x+y$ is rational and $x$ is rational, then $y$ is rational."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\color{green}{x=\frac{a}{b}}$ (since $x$ is rational), for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Assume, for a contradiction, that $x+y$ is rational.

Then $x+y=\frac{p}{q}$, for $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Re-arranging: $$\color{red}y=\frac{p}{q}-\color{green}x=\frac{p}{q}-\color{green}{\frac{a}{b}}=\color{red}{\frac{pb-aq}{qb}}\left(=\frac{p'}{q'}\right),$$  which is rational (it's the quotient of two integers)-- a contradiction (since $y$ was assumed to be irrational).

$\square$

...

PS: the following is not really necessary, but it's a useful question:

Why are $pb-aq$ and $qb$ integers? I'll leave you to answer that.

Answer (score 4):

Hint : Assume that x+y is a rational. What can you say about y=(x+y)-x ?

Comment: Well If x is rational plus y is irrational minus x being rational  y would become irrational?

Comment: It's a proof by contradiction. Assume that the conclusion of the proposition is false : x+y is rational. Now show that would imply a contradiction with the hypothesis : "y is irrational". Indeed, y=(x+y)-x is the difference between two rational numbers, so it is a rational number.

Answer (score 3):

Instances of this addition law are ubiquitous in concrete number systems, e.g. below.

[image]

A slight generalization reveals the *group*-theoretical essence of the matter:

**Lemma** $ $ Let $\,Q\,$ be a nonempty subset of the additive group $\,\Bbb R\,$ (or any abelian group). Let $\,\overline Q\,$ be the complement  of $\,Q\,\,$in $\,\Bbb R.\,$ Then $\,Q + \overline Q\,\subseteq\, \overline Q\!\iff\! Q - Q \subseteq Q\!\iff\! Q\,$ is a subgroup of $\,\Bbb R$.

So $\,\Bbb Q + \overline{\Bbb Q}\,\subseteq\, \overline{ \Bbb Q},\,$ i.e. rational + irrational = irrational, is simply a special case of the above, since $\,\Bbb Q\,$ is an additive subgroup of $\,\Bbb R,\,$ being closed under subtraction (so the [Subgoup Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test) applies).

Therefore the above composition law is simply a **complementary view** of the [Subgroup Test.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test) See below for the simple proof

---

The irrationals are the complement $\,\overline{\Bbb Q}\,$ of the subgroup $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb C$. But a complement of subgroup is not a subgroup since it does not contain the identity $\,0,\,$ nor is it closed under subtraction, not containing $\,\alpha -\alpha.$ However, we can do some group-like calculations with such complements, such as: rational + irrational = irrational. Such statements are a special case of the following *complementary* view of a subgroup.

**Theorem** $ $ Let $\rm\,G\,$ be a nonempty subset of an abelian group $\rm\,H,\,$ with complement set $\rm\,\bar G = H\backslash G.\,$
Then $\rm\,G\,$ is a subgroup of $\rm\,H\iff G + \bar G\, =\, \bar G. $

**Proof**  $\ $ $\rm\,G\,$ is a subgroup of $\rm\,H\iff G\,$ is closed under subtraction, so, complementing

$\begin{eqnarray} & &\ \ \rm G\text{ is a subgroup of }\, H\  fails\\
&\iff&\ \rm\ G\ -\ G\ \subseteq\, G\,\ \ fails\\
&\iff&\ \rm\ g_1\, -\ g_2 =\,\ \bar g\ \ \ for\ some\ \ g_1,g_2\in G,\ \ \bar g\in \bar G\\
&\iff&\ \rm\ g_2\, +\ \bar g\ \ =\,\ g_1\  for\ some\ \ g_1,g_2\in G,\ \ \bar g\in \bar G\\
&\iff&\ \rm\ G\ +\ \bar G\ \subseteq\ \bar G\ \ fails\qquad\ {\bf QED}
\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: Doubt: Must the group be **abelian** for the lemma to hold?

Comment: @Anant Look at the linked proof: does it require commutativity?

Comment: $g_1 - g_2 = \bar{g} \iff g_1 - g_2 + g_2 = \bar{g} + g_2 \iff g_1 = \bar{g} + g_2 \overset{\text{commutativity}}{=} g_2 + \bar{g}$. So, without commutativity, the theorem holds only for $\bar{G} + G = \bar{G}$ and not $G + \bar{G} = \bar{G}$?

Comment: @Anant But notice that the Subgroup Test can be applied in two ways, yielding both forms $$\begin{eqnarray} G - G = G &\iff& \bar G + G = \bar G\\ -G + G = G &\iff& G + \bar G = \bar G \end{eqnarray}\qquad $$

Comment: Hmm. I am not able to think of a reason :(

Comment: @Anant A reason for what?

Comment: A reason for requiring commutativity for the lemma to hold.

Comment: @Anant As we see, it works in the noncommutative case too. But the essence of the matter is already clear in the commutative case. If I make the answer too abstract then it may scare away beginners.

Comment: Ah! That clears my doubt. I was thinking that there was a genuine reason for including commutativity in the lemma/theorem statement, and tried (in vain) finding one. Thank you for this discussion. BTW, I'm very much a beginner myself :)