# If there a formal definition for the sum of two irrationals is rational if it is only the additive inverse plus some rational?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

If $x$ and $y$ are two irrational numbers and $x + y$ is a rational number, I know one of them has to be the additive inverse with/without some rational term I believe. I know it is not always the case that the sum of two irrational numbers is irrational.

for example:

$(\sqrt2 -1) + (-\sqrt2 +4) = 3$

But I can only seem to come up with examples that are of this nature and that seems to be the general consensus. But is there a formal definition stating it has to be of this form or is there a counterexample I am ignorantly unaware of.

then if $x+y\in\mathbb{Q}$ would it be true that $x-y$ would always just produce a multiple of that irrational plus some rational implying that if $x$ and $y$ are irrational and $x+y\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $x-y\not\in\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Non-trivial cases are possible as the open case $\pi+e$. This open case rules out that we have a proof that there are only "trivial" cases. On the other hand, I do not know whether such a "non-trivial" example is known (for which the sum is actually known to be rational).

Comment: If we have $a+b=r$ with $a,b$ irrational and $r$ rational, this sum can be written as $a+(r-a)$ which would again be of the "trivial" form. So, would you consider my above example trivial or not (if the sum would be rational) ?

Comment: Do you mean $\pi + e$. I understand they are non-algebraic and I think that is a bit outside the scope of what I am currently learning. I do know that case exists as it is widely famous which is yet to be solved. But I wanted to make sure if it was only for those special cases as I could not find a clear definition.

Comment: Yes, I meant $\pi+e$. So, you want to restrict to algebraic numbers ? Maybe in this case, we can show that there are no "suprising" solutions. But I have no idea how and whether this works.

Comment: I think I understand now that it only comes down to the trivial solutions. But I am excited to learn more about non-algebraic whenever I encounter them in any of my future number theory courses.

Comment: I highly recommend you read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/837721/242) and pomder the analogy of your  questions for the other "number systems" there. This should give you better intuition for the algebraic essence of the matter (and perhaps motivate you to learn some basic group theory - though that is not required to understand the ideas there).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you I will check it out!

Comment: If you need further elaboration you are welcome to pose questions in comments there (or here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not look for a formal *definition* but for a *theorem*, and also let's not talk about *consensus*. (Namely, an argument in math is either right or wrong, regardless on how many people are "for" or "against" it.)

So if $\alpha, \beta$ are irrational and $\alpha+\beta=q$ - rational, then $\beta=-\alpha+q$ - i.e. indeed $\beta$ is the inverse of $\alpha$ plus a rational constant, as you have claimed. Then $\alpha-\beta=2\alpha-q$, which must then be irrational. (Because, otherwise you would add $q$ and conclude that $2\alpha$ would be rational, and then you would halve it and conclude that $\alpha$ would be rational - contradiction!)

Comment: Thank you, you reminded me of my my professor in a good way. Should I correct my post to use the language you suggested?

Comment: If you did, then the first paragraph in my answer would stop making sense ;)

Comment: Of course, I just want to make sure I am using proper language with other math peeps. I want to be strict with my math syntax as I am trying to improve myself, so I appreciate the correction.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but it is trivial.  Say $x,y$ are two rational numbers, but $x+y = r$ is rational.  Then the sum is of the form
$$
x + y = (x+0) + (-x+r) = r
$$